# Error in nNetbeans saying bean class not found when pulling from Git

Tags: java, netbeans-8, smartgit

[image]

These are the errors i am getting. The `poitemlist_Bean` is not found in my project but i am not able to create one , when i try it says class already exists.

I am working on **windows 10, netbeans IDE 8.2, and smartGit** . When I try to pull or commit or push new changes I am getting rebase failed error. After cloning new project when I try to run in NetBeans I am getting multiple errors like some bean classes are missing and when I try to create that bean it says bean already exits which I am not able to find in any package.

I am working in java project.

I have already tried cloning and commenting the pages with problems. My program runs that way but then I am not able to commit or push to git.
 Please help me fix it.

Comment: Hi, Please post stack traces / screen shots so that users can give accurate and specific solutions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: And for the person who upvoted this question: this question isn't answerable. There is no point in upvoting content that we can't do anything about.

Comment: You apparently did not add the necessary jar files to your project

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I solved the problem by changing the name of the bean class and some functions.